# How to retrieve the authorization token from the response header of an ajax call in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http-headers

Basically the title has described everything. I send an api call, get a response, with `Authorization` in the header, and I want to retrieve this authorization token from the header because it is needed for subsuquent api calls. How should I get this info?

Comment: If you're using $http, the response [headers are passed to the resulting promise](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)... What more do you need?

Comment: @rixo I guess it's probably because my api call is a cross-domain one. I cannot see the Authorization part.

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

```
$http.get('yourUrl').
  success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    console.log(headers);
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

`$http` passes `headers` to the success/error callbacks. The `headers` parameter is a function that takes a single argument that is an array. It returns all those header values as an array result.

```
$http.get('/someUrl')
     .success(function(data, status, headers) {
         console.log(headers(['Authorization']));
     });
```